# Отображение фото Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Я загружаю фотографию на страницу обычной кнопкой. Как мне сделать так, чтобы отображалась ее миниатюра в  после кнопки загрузить. Я читал что надо через метод `URL.createObjectURL()`, но не понимаю как его использовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
 <input type="file" @change="onFileSelected">
        <button @click="onUpload">Загрузить</button>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="../assets/03.expert.inspection.photo.png"/>
          <h3>Спереди слева</h3>
        </div>
```

Загрузка фото через API:

```
data() {
    return {
      selectedFile: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    },
    onUpload() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(this.selectedFile.name, this.selectedFile);
      formData.append('name', 'files');
      axios.post('api/v1/files/create', {
        count: 1,
      }, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`,
        },
      })
        .then(() => axios.put('api/v1/files', formData, {
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`,
          },
          // onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          //  console.log(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
        //  },
        }));
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно привязать картинку к дате, и ее менять при заливе.
`<img :src="ImageSrc"/>` а ImageSrc меняйте динамически

https://codepen.io/Rusic/pen/BOybRW

update: для примера добавил input если с нем менять ссылку, картинка динамически меняется.